# How to crack rar file with protected pass with only the AES-256 key

Tags: aes, file-encryption

I have rar with protected pass.But I have the AES-256 key can I crack it and if I can. how?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is about cryptography itself. Questions that are about how to perform certain operations in cryptography related applications are off topic.

Comment: become an NSA-operative